# Proxying from the HTTPS port

Tags: node.js, proxy, http-proxy

I have an issue with proxying HTTPS port in my NodeJS Server. I have two localhost that I want to use: backend working on 8080 (HTTPS), and development port on 4000.

In my code, I have the following:

```
 var app = express();

var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    ws: true
});

 var REMOTE = {
    HTTP: 'https://localhost:8080',
    WS: 'ws://localhost:8080'
 };
    app.all("/api/*", function (req, res) {
        apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: REMOTE.HTTP,secure: true});
    });

app.all("/authentication/*", function (req, res) {
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: REMOTE.HTTP,secure: true});
});

app.all("/ws/info", function (req, res) {
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: REMOTE.HTTP,secure: true});
});

var server = app.listen(4000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Which works fine, untill the moment when I am trying to make a POST from port 4000. Then, I receive the error:

```
http-proxy/index.js:119
    throw err;
    ^

Error: self signed certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1003:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:570:8)
```

Do you have any ideas on what am I doing wrong?